# Using <br> to submit whitespace edit

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I just hit 2000 rep, and this is one of my first [review edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3331337). It appears to be working around the 'no whitespace edits' rule by adding `<br>` tags, and I'm not sure what is the best action to take.

It is marginally helpful (I hate looking at things like that too), but is this work-around for whitespace edits OK? It has also already been approved, but I wanted to check for more sober thoughts.

Comment: The dash was already there. Only the BRs were added.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I hadn't seen the dash in the original post, but do upon closer inspection. I am unfamiliar with objective-C, so it looked wrong from a C#/Python perspective

Comment: The only change I see is a whitespace change and a pair of bogus BRs.

Comment: When in doubt, view the markdown diff. In there you clearly see there's no code change. That edit was totally legit and indeed, was quickly approved. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks, I'll do that! Is there a canonical opinion on the work-around to submit whitespace edits somewhere?

Comment: @Hannele usually it's frowned upon, but only if there are other things to fix in the post. In that case, the only problem was lack of code formatting and that was indeed fixed.